# How to get selected value from @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The project is .Net framework3.5 and MVC framework 1.0

In my view I have a dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("prodlist",@Model.products)
```

an "Add Product" button

```
 <td> <input type ="button" name ="Add Product" value ="Add Product" id="Button1" /> </td>
```

and a textbox `@Html.TextBox ("prodselected")`

When I click the "Add Product" button I should be able to display the value  of the item    selected on Dropdownlist in the textbox "prodselected"

Please can someone let me know how to do it. If there is change needed in the existing code   please suggest.

The view is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel>" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

 <head id="Head1" runat="server">

<title>Submission</title>

 </head>

<body>

  <div>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
      {
        %>
        <div>
            <table>
             <tr>
              <td>
               <div id="SID">
                   <table id="tblID" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td width ="50%"> <label for="Process Inastance Id"> Process Inastance Id: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox("pInstance",@Model.processInstance) %></td>
                        <td width ="50%"> <label for ="Mail Id">Mail Id: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox("mail",@Model.mail) %> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <table id="tblDet" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0" >
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%"> <label for="Submission Number"> Submission Number: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox("sNo") %></td>
                    <td width ="50%"> <label for ="Name Insured">Name Insured: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox("nameInsured") %> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%"> <label for="Broker Code"> Broker Code: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox("brokerCode") %></td>
                    <td width ="50%"> <label for ="Broker Name">Broker Name: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox("brokerName") %> </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width="50%"> <label for="Product Code"> Product Code: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.DropDownList("prodlist",@Model.products)%></td>
                     <td> <input type ="button" name ="Add Product" value ="Add Product" id="Button1" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label for="Product Code"> Product Code Selected: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBox ("prodselected")%></td>
                    <td> <input type ="submit"  value ="Submit Submission"  /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Controller is:

```
namespace MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.Controllers
{
    public class WorkFlowTestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /WorkFlowTest/

        public ActionResult OpenSubmission(string processId, string mailId)
        {
            var SubmissionModelView = new MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel{processInstance =processId,  mail =mailId} ;
            SubmissionModelView.products = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SubmissionModelView.products.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "GL", Value = "0", Selected = true });
            SubmissionModelView.products.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Property", Value = "1" });
            SubmissionModelView.products.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Package", Value = "2" });
            SubmissionModelView.products.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Island Marine", Value = "3" });
            return View("Submission", SubmissionModelView);

        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel is:

```
   namespace MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels
   {

      public class WorkFlowTestViewModel
      {
          public string processInstance { get; set; }
          public string mail { get; set; }
          public List<SelectListItem> products;
       }
   }
```

To the view I added the jquery function as below:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel>"     %>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Button1').click(function() {
        $('#prodlist').val($('#prodselected').val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

There is no problem with the function but the prodlist does not show any value instead the alert gives me some junk jquery  :
I also tried this:
$('#prodlist option:selected').text; but this does not have selected value from prodlist too, and instead the alert gives me some junk jquery .

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Create a property in viewmodel to store the selected value from the dropdownlist

### Model

```
public class WorkFlowTestViewModel
{
    public string processInstance { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public int product { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> products;
}
```

### View

```
<td>
    <label for="Product Code">Product Code: </label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.product, Model.products)</td>
<td>
```

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OpenSubmission(WorkFlowTestViewModel model)
{
    //model.product is your dropdown value
    //your codegoes here
}
```

Here is the **[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9qMF1)**

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried this: $('#prodlist option:selected').text; but this does
> not have selected value from prodlist too, and instead the alert gives
> me some junk jquery

Try using

```
var selectedValue = $("#selectList :selected").val();
```